# datarowview binding to combobox datatemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a wpf application using mvvm. I am trying to bind my datatable  to a combobox that has a datatemplate of 2 textblocks. How do I specify the binding on these text blocks to bind to datarowview.item["columnname"]
In short, what I am trying to achieve is to bind 2 columns of my datatable to a multicolumn combo box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns our that you can simply bind to the column names just like how you blind to an object's public property.  WPF is smart enough to figure it out.